# OriginKind in XCM's `Transact`

Tags: xcm

I've had a discussion with colleagues from Crust Shadow and Moonbeam(check [here](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/issues/1836)) about `OriginKind` usage in XCM's `Transact` instruction and thought it'd be best to ask here for further explanation.

Let's assume the following scenario between Shiden & Crust Shadow (because they share the same account scheme).

- I want to send a XCM from Shiden to Crust Shadow, as a normal user (no special privileges)
- on Shiden, I prepare a XCM which will be sent to Crust Shadow
- instructions are `DescendOrigin`, `WithdrawAsset`, `BuyExecution` and `Transact`

  - Crust supports this instruction set and ordering
- as part of `Transact` instruction, I have to select `OriginKind`

  - this can be either `Native`, `SovereignAccount`, `Superuser` or `Xcm`

I am aware of the `OriginKind` enum description [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/53253de77f1649ecbb650df2ec3e29d0d1110a2d/xcm/src/v0/mod.rs#L60) but am unsure which type is the correct one to use here.
My understanding was that I should use `Native` since I want the destination (Crust) to interpret this as if I'm just a normal user (not with sovereign account privileges). In case I'd specify `SovereignAccount`, this would imply I want to execute something with Shiden's sovereign account privileges. I'd expect to be rejected in this case.

After discussion and repeated looks at the code, I guess my understanding was incorrect but it's still unclear to me how `OriginKind` should be interpreted.

Is `Native` only for cases when I want to execute XCM locally (e.g. via `polkadot-xcm => execute` call)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could find a lot of info in this file: [origin_conversion.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs)

Your focus is the **difference between `Native` and `SovereignAccount`**, I will try to explain these two first.

If you use `SovereignAccount`, it just [signed(location)](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs#L49). Buf if you use `Native` and send it to other chain, it will be wrapped in an Origin, may be [`Origin::Parachain(paraId)`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs#L136), or [`Origin::SiblingParachain(paraId)`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs#L162), or [`Origin::Relay`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs#L182), it depends on what is the sender chain and the xcm_config of receiver chain. And please note that **if you choose `Native` and send from a parachain, it owns the parachain privileges**, and you should use **sudo or governance to send it**(like request initOpenHrmp), otherwise it will [`match`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs#L161) failed due to `DescendOrigin` change the origin location.

---

Let's see **an example to compare SovereignAccount and Native**：
ParaA send XCM to relay_chain, transact call `hrmp.hrmpCloseChannelRequests`.

If you use `SovereignAccount` and send it to relay_chain, it will failed because [`ensure_parachain`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/parachains/src/hrmp.rs#L504) needs to make sure the account have sender chain privileges and is `Origin::Parachain(paraId)`.

Then we should use `Native` and send it to relay_chain, converted by [`ChildParachainAsNative`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs#L136), it will be `Origin::Parachain(paraId)`, and can pass the [`ensure_parachain`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/parachains/src/origin.rs#L27).

---

**`OriginKind::Superuser`** can be used in a scenario like call `assets.forceCreate`(on statemint) from relaychain. We should send the XCM via sudo or governance, then origin will be converted by [`ParentAsSuperuser`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs#L65), it will be root and can pass [`AssetsForceOrigin`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemint/src/lib.rs#L258).

Comment: Thank you @Guantong, this is a great and detailed answer!

I did check the origin_conversion.rs file before but I must have interpreted the info differently. My understanding of Native and Sovereign in this case was swapped.