# How are the costs of XCM messages designed?

Tags: xcm, weight, balances, cumulus, hrmp

after playing with the *Substrate Cumulus Parachain Template* and the *ping-pallet* to get an idea of how to use XCM, I built a local Rococo testnet connected to two parachains.

In my code, at some point, the two parachains exchange XCM messages like in this image:

[image: simple xcm exchange example]

- "step 1" Alice send a signed extrinsic call to parachain A, which triggers a XCM transact call towards parachain B
- "step 2" parachain B receive the XCM transact call, execute the extrinsic function, and triggers a reply XCM transact call towards parachain A
- "step 3" parachain A receive the XCM transact call, execute the extrinsic function

My question is: **How are the costs of XCM messages designed?**

I see that Alice pays for the extrinsic execution in "step 1". But in "step 2" and "step 3" there is no extrinsic costs for the XCM transact call, despite using a weight higher than 0 on the called extrinsic !?

Maybe the XCM transact `origin_type` has to do something with it but I don't understand it well.

Note: All XCM transact are using `origin_type: OriginKind::Native`. Also all the code works, my question is only about how the XCM interaction are being paid and how incentivization mechanism around XCM works.

Comment: I missed this question https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5074/501 which is only a piece of the answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since XCM is configurable, this can depend from chain to chain. However, most(if not all) Dotsama chains adopt the same approach. We rely on parity's implementation of `XcmExecutor` ([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/53253de77f1649ecbb650df2ec3e29d0d1110a2d/xcm/xcm-executor)) and various *off-the-shelf* implementation of various traits from the `xcm-builder` [crate](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/53253de77f1649ecbb650df2ec3e29d0d1110a2d/xcm/xcm-builder).

#### XCM Instruction Weight

Each XCM instruction has a certain *weight* since executing it takes some time. How XCM instructions are weighed is configured via `XcmConfig`,by setting `type Weigher` to some type.

E.g `polkadot` uses `FixedWeightBounds`([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/2b0d83258089578b65712e143c794cf4922941de/xcm/xcm-builder/src/weight.rs#L31) and [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L144)) which will assign fixed weight to each XCM instruction with few exceptions. E.g. `Transact`'s weight will consist of fixed weight + the weight of the call being transacted.

Using this approach, we can calculate the sum of weights for all the XCM instructions in a sequence. E.g. sequence `{ WithdrawAsset, BuyExecution, Transact }` can be weighed as `Weigher::weigh(WithdrawAsset) + Weigher::weigh(BuyExecution) + Weigher::weigh(Transact)`.

#### Paying For Xcm Execution

Let's assume for the sake of this example that we receive a XCM sent by a user with normal privileges (not `root` or `sovereign-account`). Like in you case above, `Alice` sends XCM from one chain to another.

Since `Alice` isn't a privileged user, she has to pay for executing transaction on *Parachain-A*, as you already noted. She also has to pay for XCM execution on the *Parachain-B*.

How much she has to pay and what currencies are supported for payment is once again configured by each chain. The setting type related to this is `type Trader`([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-executor/src/config.rs#L54)). In case of `Polkadot`, it just supports native `DOT` as payment asset ([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L146) and [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/2b0d83258089578b65712e143c794cf4922941de/xcm/xcm-builder/src/weight.rs#L244)). Same as with any other transaction on `Polkadot`, execution fee is correlated with weight - the more *heavy* the XCM is, the more you have to pay.

It's worth noting that many parachains allow XCM execution payment to be done in non-native asset. E.g. `Astar` has a configurable pallet that allows us to configure non-native asset as payment assets ([here](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/runtime/astar/src/xcm_config.rs#L151)). Other parachains also use basically the same approach.

If you don't intend to pay for execution, chains will simply block your XCM and discard it. This is configured via `type Barrier` ([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-executor/src/config.rs#L48) and [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L122)). Most relevant `Barrier` for `Alice` in this example is probably `AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom` ([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/53253de77f1649ecbb650df2ec3e29d0d1110a2d/xcm/xcm-builder/src/barriers.rs#L55)). It requires that the first message in XCM sequence is one that will put some assets into the holding register. This command should be followed-up by `BuyExecution` command which ensures you can pay for the follow-up XCM instructions you want to execute on the destination chain.

For the sake of example, let's assume the first XCM instruction is `WithdrawAsset`. Executing this in *Parachain-B* will attempt to withdraw some funds from `Alice`-derived account there. Which account is used, yet again depends on chain configuration. In case you're sending XCM from e.g. `Astar` to `Polkadot`, no new account would be derived and your public key would just be used on `Polkadot`. This would mean that `Alice` has to have some `DOT` in her account on `Polkadot`.

After this, `BuyExecution` is executed and some `DOTs` are spent to pay for XCM execution on `Polkadot`.

Hope this helps you :)

EDIT: regarding `OriginKind`, maybe [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5066/originkind-in-xcms-transact) topic can be of help to you. It was quite confusing to me as well.