# Why does opening an HRMP channel use the Transact instruction instead of the HrmpNewChannelOpenRequest instruction?

Tags: hrmp

Following the instructions in this post:
[How to open HRMP channels between parachains?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/how-to-open-hrmp-channels-between-parachains)
It lloks like the following instructions are required to open an HRMP channel:

- WithdrawAsset
- BuyExecution
- RefundSurplus
- DepositAsset
- Transact (to hold the encoded call for the request to open a channel)

But there's also the HrmpNewChannelOpenRequest instruction available to select. What's the use case for that instruction?

Answer (score 1):

`HrmpNewChannelOpenRequest` instruction is not implemented yet in xcm-executor, https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.31/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L507