# FailedToTransactAsset when trying to establish HRMP when using XCM

Tags: xcm, rococo, xcmp, hrmp

Getting error: `FailedToTransactAsset`

**Sender**: 2113

**Receiver**: 2000

**Sovereign account of 2113:** 5Dt6dpkWPwLaH4BBCKJwjiWrFVAGyYk3tLUabvyn4v7KtESG
(contains ~5 ROC)

This is the [call](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkabsoup1.jelliedowl.com#/extrinsics/decode/0x5d028400da8255623a48e0cff4c515aa835ad22f0f4f4390945e7308f830d09e7ad79e74017e9b2751c1f156a613f338ceeb4d566fdf21a524eade047d4bfe4417c16d882fec06eb7f764f7f5fbc754be7a233d5098973a1ca34e8c6ffc4b48e9b2a4afc8fb4002c0004001f00010100020c000400000000070010a5d4e81300000000070010a5d4e80006000700f2052a01183c0141080000) made to make the HRMP request from 2113 to 2000.

The transaction from polkadotXcm was successful. But in the relay chain... [image]

Incomplete Transaction.

`FailedToTransactAsset`

Also I deposited 5 ROC but now my sovereign account has 5.19999 meaning it has gained some ROC somehow.

The main question is what causes this error? Does it need more than 5?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the description of the error you are getting:

```rust
/// An asset transaction (like withdraw or deposit) failed (typically due to type conversions).
#[codec(index = 9)]
FailedToTransactAsset(#[codec(skip)] &'static str),
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/53253de77f1649ecbb650df2ec3e29d0d1110a2d/xcm/src/v2/traits.rs#L56-L58

Looks like the encoded call that you are executing is an `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel` to accept a channel open request from para 2,113:

[image]

Therefore you need to make sure that the sovereign account for para 2000 is funded. Para 2000 is accepting the `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel` request from para 2,113. And you would want to do this `polkadotXCM` call on para 2000.

More info here:

- [How to open HRMP channels between parachains?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/how-to-open-hrmp-channels-between-parachains)

Comment: aha so 2000 need to fund their sovereign account perhaps let me check