# What is the purpose of Sovereign account? How is the balance of Soverign for a Parachain decided or calculated?

Tags: xcm, relay-chain, xcmp

I think that balance of Sovereign account on Relay chain should be total token supply for that parachain?

Basically what's the relation between soverign account balance and parachain?

How does it affected by XCM operatipn to transfer asset ?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding.

It's because the Substrate uses the `Origin` design.

Sovereign represents the `Origin` of a chain.

Imagine you send an HRMP channel opening request. Who should be the sender? Your account? Apparently not. It should be the account of the parachain.

Comment: You didn't say how its balance  operated?

Comment: Let's see an example to compare SovereignAccount and Native： ParaA send XCM to relay_chain, transact call hrmp.hrmpCloseChannelRequests.

If you use SovereignAccount and send it to relay_chain, it will failed because ensure_parachain needs to make sure the account have sender chain privileges and is Origin::Parachain(paraId).

Then we should use Native and send it to relay_chain, converted by ChildParachainAsNative, it will be Origin::Parachain(paraId), and can pass the ensure_parachain.  from https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5066/originkind-in-xcms-transact

Comment: Wouldn't above be applied for opening the channel too?

Comment: You need to transfer some tokens to this account first. Then use the sudo/governance to manage this account.