# Send upward message to unlock parachain

Tags: parachain, xcm, relay-chain

After [PR5451](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5451), it is possible to "unlock" parachain so that the state can be set by the parachain account on relaychain. But its unclear how to send this message from the parachain to relaychain. I have tried `Transact -> Encoded call(remove_lock)` but this fails with the `Barrier` error. Has anyone used this? What is the correct way to send the `remove_lock` message to the relaychain.

Comment: Please include more details. What is the exact XCM message you sent?What does your xcm_config look like? How do you have your barriers set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important in this case is that the XCM message must have the native origin. You can only achieve this if you write a wrapper pallet that will send a UMP message from within a dispatchable.

This is how we did it to initiate our parachain slot swap on the relay chain: https://github.com/integritee-network/pallets/blob/master/xcm-transactor/src/lib.rs#L92

Note: As this allows to send an XCM message with the parachain as origin, you need to make sure that this dispatchable can't be called by anyone for security reasons. It should require the sudo/governance origin. even if this is not problematic for this particular relay chain call at hand.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons that could lead to this error, I'll list a few possible ones.

1. You should send the message via **sudo or governance**.
2. Your parachain sovereignAccount on relaychain should have enough tokens.
3. The `Transact` instruction should use **Native** Origin, you can check [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5066/originkind-in-xcms-transact/5074#5074).
4. You should Add `WithdrawAsset` and `BuyExecution` instructions before `Transact` instruction, also note, relychain assetId is `{parents: 0, interior: Here}`